# Solving fourth order diffusion type equation using Finite Difference method

Tags: finite-differences, finite-difference-methods

I am trying to solve a fourth order partial differential equation
$$ {\partial u\over \partial t} = i{\partial^4 u\over \partial x^4} $$
where $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and periodic boundary conditions.

I tried using first order in time and 2nd order in space finite difference scheme, even second order in time and space also. But I am unable to formulate a FD scheme with is stable. I am trying to check stability using von-Neumann stability criteria. Could somebody explain how to proceed in this case?

Comment: What size $\Delta t$ and $\Delta x$ are you using?  Using FD methods on that equation will require painfully small values to be stable

Comment: I am currently using 1e-4 for both space and time. The length of both space and time is 1. But the problem is I can't prove using von-Neumann stability criteria that the scheme is stable

Answer (score 1):

Let's try the [second order accurate central finite difference for the spatial variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient#Central_finite_difference) and [Backward Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_Euler_method) for the temporal discretization. Then, your discretized PDE reads:
$$\frac{u_j^{k+1} - u_j^k}{\Delta t} = i \frac{u_{j-2}^{k+1} - 4u_{j-1}^{k+1} + 6 u_{j}^{k+1} -4 u_{j+1}^{k+1} + u_{j+2}^{k+1} }{\Delta x^4}$$
Now [make the usual Ansatz for a von-Neumann stability analysis](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-336-numerical-methods-for-partial-differential-equations-spring-2009/lecture-notes/MIT18_336S09_lec14.pdf) $$u_j^k = e^{ikx_j}$$
and get your hands dirty:
\begin{align}
u_j^{k+1} &= e^{ikx_j} + \underbrace{r}_{i \Delta t / \Delta x^4} \Big( e^{i(k+1) (x_j - 2 \Delta x)} - 4 e^{i(k+1) (x_j - \Delta x)} + 6e^{i(k+1)x_j} \\
& \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad - 4 e^{i(k+1) (x_j + \Delta x)} +  e^{i(k+1) (x_j + 2\Delta x)}  \Big) \\
&= e^{ikx_j} + r \Big( e^{ik x_j } e^{i (x_j - 2 \Delta xk - 2 \Delta x)} - 4 e^{ikx_j} e^{i(x_j -k\Delta x - \Delta x) } + 6e^{ik x_j } e^{ix_j} \\ &\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad - 4 e^{ik x_j } e^{i (x_j + k\Delta x + \Delta x)} +  e^{ik x_j } e^{i(x_j + 2\Delta x + 2 \Delta x k)}  \Big) \\
&= e^{ik x_j } \Big[ 1 + r \Big( e^{i (x_j - 2 \Delta xk - 2 \Delta x)} - 4 e^{i(x_j -k\Delta x - \Delta x) } + 6 e^{ix_j} \\
& \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad - 4 e^{i (x_j + k\Delta x + \Delta x)} + e^{i(x_j + 2\Delta x + 2 \Delta x k)} \Big) \Big]
\end{align}

[By Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=exp%28i%28x%20-%202%20a%20k%20-%202%20a%29%20%29%20-%204%20exp%28i%28x%20-k%20a%20-a%29%29%20%2B%206%20exp%28ix%29%20-%204%20exp%28i%28x%20%2B%20ka%20%2Ba%29%29%20%2B%20exp%28i%28x%20%2B%202a%20%2B%202ak%29%29),
\begin{align}& e^{i (x_j - 2 \Delta xk - 2 \Delta x)} - 4 e^{i(x_j -k\Delta x - \Delta x) } + 6 e^{ix_j} - 4 e^{i (x_j + k\Delta x + \Delta x)} + e^{i(x_j + 2\Delta x + 2 \Delta x k)} \\
 =& 16 e^{ix_j} \sin^4\Big( 0.5\Delta x [k+1] \Big)\end{align}

And using Euler's formula $e^{ix_j} = \cos(x_j) + i \sin(x_j)$

\begin{align}
&r \Big( e^{i (x_j - 2 \Delta xk - 2 \Delta x)} - 4 e^{i(x_j -k\Delta x - \Delta x) } + 6 e^{ix_j} - 4 e^{i (x_j + k\Delta x + \Delta x)} + e^{i(x_j + 2\Delta x + 2 \Delta x k)}  \Big) \\
=& \underbrace{16 \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x^4} \sin^4\Big( 0.5\Delta x [k+1] \Big)}_{=: \alpha(k)} \big[ i \cos(x_j) - \sin(x_j) \big]
\end{align}

Thus, the absolute value of the amplification $$ |G|  = \Big \vert 1 + r \Big( e^{i (x_j - 2 \Delta xk - 2 \Delta x)} - 4 e^{i(x_j -k\Delta x - \Delta x) } + 6 e^{ix_j} - 4 e^{i (x_j + k\Delta x + \Delta x)} + e^{i(x_j + 2\Delta x + 2 \Delta x k)} \Big) \Big \vert$$
is given by
\begin{align}
 |G|^2 &= \alpha(k)^2 \cos(x_j)^2 + (1 - \alpha(k) \sin(x_j)^2) \\
  &=  \alpha(k)^2 \cos(x_j)^2 + \alpha(k)^2 \sin(x_j)^2+ 1 - 2 \alpha(k) \sin(x_j) \\
&= \alpha(k)^2 + 1 - 2 \alpha(k) = (\alpha(k) - 1)^2 
\end{align}
So to have stability $|G| < 1$, we require
\begin{align}
\vert \alpha(k) - 1 \vert < 1 
\end{align}
Note that it holds $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}_0, \Delta t > 0, \Delta x >0$:
$$0 < \alpha (k) \leq 16 \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x^4} $$
Thus if you guarantee that
$$ 16 \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x^4} -1 < 1$$ you have stability.